# How to change the problem solving format to use lambda and/or map (Python)

Tags: python, lambda, map-function

I'm trying to code the following formula:

[image]

To do this I'm using the following function:

```
def predict(x, w):
    """
    Function to predict y(x, w) based on the values of x and w.
    
    Args: 
        x: a vector including all the values of the input variable x for a given set of point.
        w: polynomial coefficient vector.
        
    Returns: an array with the predicted values for y(x, w) function.
    """
    x = np.array(x)
    w = np.array(w)
    # list of powers for x. {0, 1, 2 ... M}
    powers = list(range(0, len(w)))
    
    # apply the polynomial fitting function to each value of vectors x & w
    sumatoria_list = sum(np.array([w[i] * (x ** i) for i in powers]))
    
    # return final sum
    return sumatoria_list
```

In the image below you can see examples of input and output:

[image]

Where:

```
w0 = [-0.17594739490150393]
w1 = [0.7237871780107422, -1.7994691458244925]
x = array([0.        , 0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.44444444,
       0.55555556, 0.66666667, 0.77777778, 0.88888889, 1.        ])
```

So far the output of my function is correct, however, I'm trying to use lambda:

```
def predict1(x, w):
    """
    Function to predict y(x, w) based on the values of x and w.
    
    Args: 
        x: a vector including all the values of the input variable x for a given set of point.
        w: polynomial coefficient vector.
        
    Returns: an array with the predicted values for y(x, w).
    """
    x = np.array(x)
    w = np.array(w)
    # list of powers for x. {0, 1, 2 ... M}
    powers = list(range(0, len(w)))
    
    # apply the polynomial fitting function to each value of vectors x & w
    sumatoria_list = list(map(lambda x, w, i: w * (x ** i), x, w, powers))
    
    # return final sum
    return sumatoria_list
```

Nevertheless, it seems not to be working right. In the image below you can find examples of output using `lambda` and `map` in the function.

[image]

I think that I'm not quite understanding how to apply lambda to this specific problem so I would really appreciate your help!!

Comment: in your correct code, are you getting a vector output for `sum(np.array([w[i] * (x ** i) for i in powers]))`? That doesn't seem right!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work now,

#### Requested Solution

**Code Syntax**

```
w = [0.7237871780107422, -1.7994691458244925]
x = [0., 0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.44444444, 0.55555556, 0.66666667, 0.77777778, 0.88888889, 1.        ]

powers = list(range(0, len(w)))
print("power list: ", powers)
print("w: ", w)
lista = list(map(lambda rng, x: w[rng] * (x ** rng) ,powers, x))

print(lista)
```

**Output**

```
power list:  [0, 1]
w:  [0.7237871780107422, -1.7994691458244925]

[0.7237871780107422, -0.19994101420331123]

[Program finished]
```

---

#### Explanation

The reason for not giving you the required output is you can't operate `pow()` or operating full list with others, you have to iterate both lists to give you the required output.

For example:

> *Giving listA = [1, 2, 3], and listB = [1, 2, 2]. If you want to operate both lists, you've to iterate them, first.*

**Code Syntax**

```
listC = list(map(lambda x, y: x ** y, listA, listB))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 4, 9]

[Program finished]
```

Or, you can use only `map()` for **mathematical operation**

**Code Syntax**

```
listC2 = list(map(pow, listA, listB))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 4, 9]

[Program finished]
```

Comment: It is not working. I'm getting as output what is shown in the third picture while my desired output is what is shown in the second image. Also, both x & w are arrays.

Comment: if that so, the `powers` length must be with the `x` not `w` according to your second image. now, this's a glitch

Comment: you `w` variable has only 2 values in its list, So, the question is how do you have 10 values as variable `x` length, not `w` length!!!!